# Sorting time ranges with Pandas where overlaps exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I have the following dataframe which shows instructions received to perform an action - as an overview of columns, instructions come as a group which is highlighted by the columns Number, each instruction tells you to go from level 'levelFrom' at time 'timeFrom' to level 'levelTo' at time 'timeTo'. E.g. instruction 9166 says to go from level 0 at 11:55 to level 18 at 11:59, stay at level 18 from 11:59 to 12:24, and then go from level 18 at 12:24 back to level 0 at 12:27.

| timeFrom | timeTo | Number | LevelFrom | LevelTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-06 11:55:00 | 2024-01-06 11:59:00 | 9166.0 | 0.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 11:59:00 | 2024-01-06 12:24:00 | 9166.0 | 18.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 12:24:00 | 2024-01-06 12:27:00 | 9166.0 | 18.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 12:24:00 | 2024-01-06 12:52:00 | 9167.0 | 18.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 12:52:00 | 2024-01-06 12:55:00 | 9167.0 | 18.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:10:00 | 2024-01-06 14:14:00 | 9168.0 | 0.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:14:00 | 2024-01-06 14:39:00 | 9168.0 | 18.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:39:00 | 2024-01-06 14:42:00 | 9168.0 | 18.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:21:00 | 2024-01-06 14:22:00 | 9169.0 | 18.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:22:00 | 2024-01-06 14:47:00 | 9169.0 | 19.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:47:00 | 2024-01-06 14:50:00 | 9169.0 | 19.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:01:00 | 2024-01-06 15:05:00 | 9170.0 | 20.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:35:00 | 2024-01-06 14:36:00 | 9170.0 | 19.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:36:00 | 2024-01-06 15:01:00 | 9170.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:01:00 | 2024-01-06 15:15:00 | 9171.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:15:00 | 2024-01-06 15:19:00 | 9171.0 | 20.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:15:00 | 2024-01-06 15:35:00 | 9172.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:35:00 | 2024-01-06 15:39:00 | 9172.0 | 20.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:35:00 | 2024-01-06 15:36:00 | 9173.0 | 20.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:36:00 | 2024-01-06 15:37:00 | 9173.0 | 19.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:37:00 | 2024-01-06 15:40:00 | 9173.0 | 19.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 15:32:00 | 2024-01-06 16:02:00 | 9174.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 16:02:00 | 2024-01-06 16:06:00 | 9174.0 | 20.0 | 0.0 |

As you can see from the table, later instructions can supersede parts of a previous instruction. E.g. instruction 9167 says to stay at level 18 until 12:52 rather than stepping down at 1224 as per instruction 9166.

What I need is to get a snapshot of the final position once all instructions have been received. I.e. sort the table such that instructions give a continuous 'story' from their start time to their end time. NB: where instructions are disjoint, they should stay disjoint.

I think what I should do is look at instruction numbers in pairs and string them together to get a continuous timeline, and then continue pairwise until the next instruction is disjoint but I'm not too sure how to go about this. I don't hugely care about retaining instruction numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For completeness, the final table in this example should look like:

| timeFrom | timeTo | Number | LevelFrom | LevelTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-06 11:55:00 | 2024-01-06 11:59:00 | 9166.0 | 0.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 11:59:00 | 2024-01-06 12:52:00 | 9166.0 | 18.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 12:52:00 | 2024-01-06 12:55:00 | 9166.0 | 18.0 | 0.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:10:00 | 2024-01-06 14:14:00 | 9168.0 | 0.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:14:00 | 2024-01-06 14:21:00 | 9168.0 | 18.0 | 18.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:21:00 | 2024-01-06 14:22:00 | 9168.0 | 18.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:22:00 | 2024-01-06 14:35:00 | 9169.0 | 19.0 | 19.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:35:00 | 2024-01-06 14:36:00 | 9169.0 | 19.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 14:36:00 | 2024-01-06 16:02:00 | 9169.0 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 2024-01-06 16:02:00 | 2024-01-06 16:06:00 | 9170.0 | 20.0 | 0.0 |

Comment: To finalise your problem framing, a priority rule is needed: do we need to maximise the level for example?

Comment: The latest instruction should always be the priority. I.e. if instruction number (x+1) overlaps with something from instruction number (x) then x is overwritten by (x+1) regardless of what the levels are doing.

Comment: With your output data 9166 is showing but 9167 is not showing. But 9167 finishes after 9166 and they both finish on level 0. Is that correct?

Comment: Further questions to understand before proposing a solution: 1) on the second row of your output table, the "time from" is given by 9166, and the "time to" by 9167. Do you want a rule to be applied to determine the value in output? 2) Shouldn't the number on the third row of the output table be 9167?

Comment: Once the data is ordered as per the output table the 'Number' column becomes irrelevant so it's not important which instruction number is shown where, I'll just remove the column altogether from the output table in the question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: If the 'Number' column is not important that a simple index might have helped.

Comment: I don't have the time to write the code now, but here is what my first attempt would be:
1) Order by "time from"
2) Delete all rows whose number is not the rolling max since the beginning
3) If 'time to"(t) > "time from"(t+1) --> "time to"(t) = time from"(t+1)
4) Delete all rows where "time from" <= "time to"

Comment: That strategy almost works but in the above example timeFrom[8] != timeTo[9] in the output table as expected. I've run it for another example case and similar problems have occurred at a few points throughout - I've not managed to figure out exactly what the problem is yet. This is a huge step forwards though, thanks!

Comment: ^^ Figured it out, at the timeTo[k] > timeFrom[k+1] stage, I had to add a check that Number[k+1] >= rolling max otherwise it was taking the end time of row k to be a superseded start time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you reshape the data so it is a single timeline.

[image]